# How to subtract control group values from multiple treatmeant groups' values in R data frame?

Tags: r, for-loop, subset

I have a following data frame in R:

| Group | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Control | 2 |
| Control | 3 |
| Treament1 | 7 |
| Treament1 | 4 |
| Treament2 | 5 |
| Treament2 | 6 |

How do I get:

| Group | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Treament1 - Control | 5 |
| Treament1 - Control | 1 |
| Treament2 - Control | 3 |
| Treament2 - Control | 0 |

I was thinking of looping and using the subset function:

```
controldf <- subset(df, Group == "Control")
newdf <- subset(df, Group != "Control")
newvalue <- c()
for(group in unique(df$group)) {
    if(group != "Control") {
        newvalue <- c(newvalue, subset(df, Group == group)$value - controldf$value)
    }
}
newdf$value <- newvalue
```

...but this looks bad (and is very slow with larger data frames). :(

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The lower table is showing correctly in the preview, but not when published, weird...

Comment: It looks like the table of what you want isn't showing up. Can you try making it again or maybe a screenshot of a spreadsheet or something?

Comment: @andrewb Now it is showing correctly. I had to add an extra new line before the table, and that fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution 1 uses `dplyr` and `tidyr` libraries. An `id` column is added to the data.frame assuming that subjects are ordered within group.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df |>
    group_by(Group) |>
    mutate(id = row_number()) |>
    pivot_wider(names_from = Group, values_from = Value) |>
    mutate(across(starts_with("Treament"), ~.x - Control))  |>
    select(starts_with("Treament")) |>
    rename_with(~sprintf("%s - Control", .x)) |>
    pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "Group", values_to = "Value") |>
    arrange(Group)
##>  # A tibble: 4 × 2
##>   Group               Value
##>   <chr>               <int>
##> 1 Treament1 - Control     5
##> 2 Treament1 - Control     1
##> 3 Treament2 - Control     3
##> 4 Treament2 - Control     3
```

Solution 2 uses the `purrr` library:

```r
library(purrr)

spl <- with(df, split(Value, Group))

imap_dfr(spl[startsWith(names(spl), "Treament")], ~{
    data.frame(Group= sprintf("%s - Control", .y),
               Value = .x - spl$Control)
    })

##>                 Group Value
##> 1 Treament1 - Control     5
##> 2 Treament1 - Control     1
##> 3 Treament2 - Control     3
##> 4 Treament2 - Control     3
```